# Calculate area ( in sq feet or mile or meter ) of places received from google map api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, area

- Hello Team ,
  I am using following google map api to load near by restaurants

Request
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotel&name=hotel&location=".$lat.",".$long."&radius=100&key=".$apikey,
Response

```
 "error": false,
    "TotalHotel": 20,
    "error_msg": "Result get successfully",
    "responseData": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 23.012823,
                    "lng": 72.512951
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 23.014277980291,
                        "lng": 72.514332580292
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 23.011580019709,
                        "lng": 72.511634619709
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
            "id": "9743bcfaf87a51845c3373573677fdba80976393",
            "name": "Platinum Residency",
            "vicinity": "Opp Shell Petrol Pump,Prahladnagar, Nr. Prahladnagar Garden, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India",
            "place_id": "ChIJ8_qnyIqEXjkRdgP60epDbkA",
            "distance": "1 ft"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 23.0115762,
                    "lng": 72.5052773
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 23.012925180292,
                        "lng": 72.506626280292
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 23.010227219709,
                        "lng": 72.503928319708
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
            "id": "d1100b67cdeadfabb5454786667da5c97504ccd6",
            "name": "Hotel Mukund Inn",
            "vicinity": "2nd Floor, Pushpak Complex, Above KFC Restaurant, Opp. Prahladnagar Garden, SG Highway, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380054, India",
            "place_id": "ChIJZ2HqtsyaXjkR7KRTp9PzTEY",
            "distance": "0.6 mi"
        },
```

My question here is that if there is any parameter from google is available which will help me to calculate area of places. I.e Hotel blue places occupied/ compound of 200 sq feet

Comment: Aren't the northeast and southwest coordinates enough?

Comment: @delboy1978uk  Do you mean I can calculate area using northeast and southwest coordinates ?

Comment: well, a north west point and a south east point will give you a rectangle with a length and a height, so calculating that area should be trivial. of course it's under the `viewport`, so i'm guessing thats the total area you can see in the map?